# Why does $g\circ \exp(tv) \circ g^{-1}$ give the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated by $g_* v$?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, symplectic-geometry, pushforward

I have a question regarding the following proof from Cannas da Silva - Introduction to Symplectic and Hamiltonian Geometry:

> Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $\alpha$ be a 1-form such that
>   $\omega = −d\alpha$.
>   There exists a unique vector field $v$ such that its interior product with
>   $\omega$ is $-\alpha$, i.e., $\iota_v \omega = −\alpha$.
>
> **Proposition 2.3** If $g$ is a symplectomorphism which preserves $\alpha$
>   (that is, $g^*\alpha = \alpha$), then $g$ commutes with the one-parameter group of
>   diffeomorphisms generated by $v$, i.e.,
>   $(\exp tv) \circ g = g \circ (\exp tv)$.
>
> **Proof.** Recall that, for $p \in M$, $(\exp tv)(p)$ is the unique curve in $M$
>   solving the ordinary differential equation
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{d}{dt}(\exp tv(p)) &= v(\exp tv(p))\\
> (\exp tv)(p)|_{t=0} &= p
> \end{align*}
>   for $t$ in some neighborhood of 0. From this is follows that $g \circ(\exp tv)\circ
> g^{−1}$ must be the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated
>   by $g_*v$. (The push-forward of $v$ by $g$ is defined by $(g_*v)_{g(p)} = dg_{p}(v_{p})$.)
>   Finally we have that $g_*v = v$, i.e., that $g$ preserves $v$.

I cannot figure out why this step holds:

> From this is follows that $g \circ(\exp tv)\circ
> g^{−1}$ must be the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated
>   by $g_*v$.

I intuitively feel that the $g^{-1}$ should be there, otherwise the positioning on the manifold is wrong after pushing forward $v$, but haven't been able to formulate anything cohesive. I also cannot figure out how to show something along the lines of $g \circ \exp (tv) = \exp (t g_* v)$. In general this won't hold, so the strict conditions on $V$ and $g$ must be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the notation $\rho_{t}:=\exp tv$. By assumption, $\rho_{t}$ is the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated by $v$, i.e.
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
\begin{cases}
\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}\rho_{s}(p)=v(\rho_{t}(p))\\
\rho_{0}(p)=p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for all $p\in M$ and all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. To see that $g\circ\rho_{t}\circ g^{-1}$ is the one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms generated by $g_{*}v$, we need to show that 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
\begin{cases}
\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}(g\circ\rho_{s}\circ g^{-1})(p)=(g_{*}v)\big((g\circ\rho_{t}\circ g^{-1})(p)\big)\\
(g\circ\rho_{0}\circ g^{-1})(p)=p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for all $p\in M$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. For the first equality in \eqref{2}, we have
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}(g\circ\rho_{s}\circ g^{-1})(p)&=(dg)_{\rho_{t}(g^{-1}(p))}\left(\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}(\rho_{s}(g^{-1}(p))\right)\\
&=(dg)_{\rho_{t}(g^{-1}(p))}\left(v(\rho_{t}(g^{-1}(p)))\right)\\
&=\left(g_{*}v\right)\left((g\circ\rho_{t}\circ g^{-1})(p)\right).
\end{align}
Here the first equality is due to the chain rule, and the second equality uses the first equation of \eqref{1} at the point $g^{-1}(p)$.

As for the second equality in \eqref{2}, just use the second equation of \eqref{1} at the point $g^{-1}(p)$.